# primeng v2.0.6 p-dialog is not a modal in angular 2.4.10

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I am using a primeng modal v2.0.6 in an angular 2.4.10 component:

The following is my html template:

```
    <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        Dino 3D Viewer Experiment
    </h1>
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section #phone class="content">
    <button pButton id="screenshot" class="no-spinner" type="button" (click)="callAlert('screenshot')"
            label="screenshot"></button>
    <button pButton id="download" class="no-spinner" type="button" (click)="downloadStl()"
            label="download geometry"></button>
    <button pButton id="dialog" class="no-spinner" type="button" (click)="showDialog()"
            label="open modal"></button>
</section>

<p-dialog header="Godfather I" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="300" [responsive]="true">
    <p>The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.
        His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's
        business.
        Through Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just
        like the head of the family,
        kind and benevolent to those who give respect,
        but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family.</p>
    <p-footer>
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
            <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="display=false" label="No"></button>
            <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" (click)="display=false" label="Yes"></button>
        </div>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

the following is my component.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dino-viewer',
  templateUrl: './dino-viewer.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dino-viewer.component.css']
})
export class dinoViewerComponent {

    display: boolean;


    callAlert(aMessage) {
        alert(aMessage);
    }

    showDialog() {
        this.display = true;
    }
}
```

and the following is the unfortunate result:
[image]

after some reading I have tried to add the following to the  element:

> appendTo="body" appendTo="@body" appendTo="@(body)"
>   appendToBody="true"

but the modal does not show as modal. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much for your help,

Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution to my own problem.

The project was missing the css libraries:

- primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css
- font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
- primeng/resources/primeng.min.css

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try updating your PrimeNG version. The latest is 4.0.2 so since you're two major updates behind its likely this and other bugs are being introduced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the new version of primeNG does not seem to like the version of Angular I am using (2.4.10)

Comment: Ok, you're right I didn't notice that. I think you'd have to update to Angular 4. Latest is 4.1.2 I believe. Hopefully someone can resolve this for you. If not you may have to run some updates!

Comment: Thank you anyway for trying. Unfortunately cannot update the current project to Angular 4, too big and Angular 4 is substantially different from Angular 2 making the migration of this mature a real nightmare. Hopefully someone will be able to help me out or point me in the right direction.